# error: too many values to unpack (expected 5) when assigning variables to columns in a DataFrame

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

the df has 5 columns excluding index.

```
for i, j, k, l, m in df['client'],df['env'],df['name'],df['tests'],df['enabled']:

  print(i,j,k,l,m)
```

returns error: too many values to unpack (expected 5)

Comment: there is missing `,` I guess

Comment: need `df['env'],df['name']` ?

Comment: @jezrael  i need to assign a variable to each column and print them in a line next to each other.

Comment: How many rows do you have in your DataFrame df?

Answer (score 1):

I guess you can use this

```
for i,row in df.iterrows():
  print(row['client'], row['env'], row['name'], row['tests'], row['enabled'])
```

Iterate on dataframe rows and print any column you want.

Or you need to use zip function

```
for i, j, k, l, m in zip(df['client'],df['env'],df['name'],df['tests'],df['enabled']):

  print(i,j,k,l,m)
```

Answer (score 0):

This error may be caused due to having unequal number of rows in your dataframe. If any rows of the dataframe contain any NaN values you can replace them with a zero and try.